# A proposito del "ma" tra due virgole

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions

1. Spesso prima di *ma* ci metto una virgola.
2. Il punto è che a volte inserisco un'inciso subito dopo il *ma*, sicché il *ma* resta isolato tra due virgole.

Del punto 1, un esempio preso da [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/virgola_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) è *"Oggi il cielo è nuvoloso, ma non è previsto che pioverà"*, ma, anche se avrei dovuto scrivere *mentre*, il presente periodo è esso stesso un esempio del punto 2.

Oppure, per essere meno criptico, un esempio di tipo 2 è il seguente

> Potrei provare ad imbrogliare a carte, ma, per il momento, preferisco affidarmi alla fortuna.

Ora non è che io nel parlato faccia queste lunghe pause per ogni virgola, ma in qualche modo le virgole come sopra mi sembrano messe con logica. Tuttavia non posso fare a meno di notare che sono tante. Specialmente le due attorno a *ma* sono molto vicine e forse appesantiscono.

C'è qualche regola o convenzione riconosciuta su come gestire questi casi?

---

[Non è che io sia il primo a farsi questa domanda.](https://www.linkuaggio.com/2013/11/virgola-prima-o-dopo-del-ma-esempi-e.html)

Comment: Io prenderei come linea guida l'articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca citato nel link che hai messo, a proposito di 'e'.  In realtà non ci sono vere e proprie regole, dice l'articolo alla fine "normalmente, l'uso della virgola resta una scelta stilistica personale, un modo per dare rilievo espressivo a singoli elementi di un testo, una maniera per conferire un particolare ritmo alla narrazione, ma, soprattutto, una scelta che determina significativamente lo stile comunicativo di un autore." "Non si mette la virgola dopo 'e'" , come  dicevano alle elementari, è una sciocchezza :-).